twilio flex unhandled exception "no active call"
I am working with a trial twilio account, my plan is to develop a custom plugin.
I have used the example react project and all was going well until I started testing with incoming calls.
I have configured a flow to route the incoming call to the default flex task queue, all good so far.
When I accept the call I get an exception that points at Error - 45600 which seems to be a catch all error pointing at custom code errors.
Error thrown in the browser is ERROR
Script error.
at handleError (http://localhost:3000/plugins/plugin-ioconnect.js:11524:58)
at http://localhost:3000/plugins/plugin-ioconnect.js:11543:7
and in the console
twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207 11/6/2024, 5:19:53 PM - WorkerActions.AcceptTask: no active call
apply @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
apply @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
e.processError @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
e.createAndProcessError @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
a @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
Promise.then
c @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
s @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
e.acceptTask @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
r @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
e.invokeAction @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
(anonymous) @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
r @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
t.tryInvokeAction @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
t.onClick @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
onClick @ twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3942
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3991
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4053
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4067
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8273
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8305
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8318
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8329
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8538
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22426
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3742
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8537
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6035
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5954
unstable_runWithPriority @ react.development.js:2764
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11306
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22443
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3753
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5919Understand this error
twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207 Uncaught Error: no active call
    at new n (twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207:6461573)
    at e.createAndProcessError (twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207:6464687)
    at twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:207:6590127

I am not calling AcceptTask all I did was click the green accept call button in the UI
I did wonder if the connectivity to the twilio call router was an issue as in the UK and the incoming number is routed via the US as the Ireland region does not appear to have any capabilities yet, and my office has poor wifi, I have moved office and I have approx 50Mbit downlink so I was hopping that was sufficient.
Still fails with the same error.
Sorry I forgot to add that when I dismiss the in page error, the call is still there I can talk to the caller, I can put the call on hold etc.
I have tried to isolate from my code as much as possible, no luck.
Does anyone have experience of this issue ?

This looks like an error from the flex ui application itself. You can check the latest release notes that the issue has been fixed https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/release-notes/flex-ui-release-notes-for-v2xx#fixed
